# Prevent automatic upgrade of manually built package

Tags: apt, package-management, 16.04

I've built leafpad from source and now apt-get thinks that it's time to update leafpad to the same version. How can I prevent it?

Detailed steps:

```
apt-get build-dep leafpad
apt-get source leafpad
cd leafpad-0.8.18.1/
dpkg-buildpackage -uc -b
sudo dpkg -i ../leafpad_0.8.18.1-4_amd64.deb
```

After installing this sample package from source, after running `apt-get dist-upgrade` I'm suggested to upgrade leafpad

Answer (score 0):

It's always best to try and use software that's in the official repositories. You'll have some assurance that it won't cause major problems with your existing software. Apt-get is telling you that leafpad already existed for you to install via Synaptic or the Software Center, and that there's an update available (and that you didn't need to build it from source code).

If you're really sure that you don't want newer versions of leafpad to install when doing software updates, then:

1. Open Synaptic (make sure that Settings/Prefs/General/Appearance has **Show package properties in main window** checkmarked).
2. search for leafpad
3. click on the versions tab
4. select the version that you installed
5. select **Lock Version** in the Packages menu